# How to use "for_each" inside the "subnet_mapping" in terraform so I can map the each elastic IPs created to each "subnet_id"

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

// This creates my EIPs:

```
resource "aws_eip" "nlb_eips" {
  count = length(module.vpc.public_subnets)
}
```

// This needs to create my NLB with EIPs attached to it:

```
resource "aws_lb" "data-lake-NLB" {

  name               = "data-lake-NLB"
  internal           = false
  load_balancer_type = "network"
  enable_deletion_protection = true
  subnet_mapping {
    for_each = {for k,v in     => ... )  }     ????? # This part I can't figure out. 
    subnet_id = each.key
    allocation_id = each.value
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [dynamic blocks](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks.html):

```
resource "aws_lb" "data-lake-NLB" {

  name               = "data-lake-NLB"
  internal           = false
  load_balancer_type = "network"
  enable_deletion_protection = true

  dynamic "subnet_mapping" {

      for_each = range(length(var.public_subnets))

      content {
         subnet_id     = module.vpc.public_subnets[ingress.key].id
         allocation_id = aws_eip.nlb_eips[ingress.key].id
      }
  }

}
```

The exact form depends on what `module.vpc.public_subnets` actually is.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I also used a different approach for it.

Answer (score 0):

```
  resource "aws_lb" "data-lake-NLB" {
  name               = "data-lake-NLB"
  internal           = false
  load_balancer_type = "network"
  enable_deletion_protection = true

  dynamic "subnet_mapping" { 
      for_each = local.for_each_map      
 aws_eip.nlb_eips[*].public_ip)
    content {
      subnet_id = subnet_mapping.key
      allocation_id = subnet_mapping.value
    }
  }
}
locals {
  for_each_map = zipmap(module.vpc.public_subnets, aws_eip.nlb_eips[*].id) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had almost the same issue (in my case IP addresses came from a variable) and had to piece together bits of the solution from different places. This is what worked for me:

```
variable "ip_addr" {
  description = "List of static IP addresses to assign to the load balancer"
  type = list
}

data "aws_subnets" "public" {
  filter {
    name = "vpc-id"
    values = [data.aws_vpc.main.id]
  }
  tags = {
    Type = "public"
  }
}

data "aws_eip" "lb" {
  count = length(var.ip_addr)
  public_ip = var.ip_addr[count.index]
}

resource "aws_lb" "gateway-lb" {
  name               = "gateway-nlb"
  internal           = false
  load_balancer_type = "network"
  idle_timeout       = 300
  enable_deletion_protection = true

  dynamic "subnet_mapping" {
    for_each = range(length(data.aws_subnets.public.ids))
    content {
      subnet_id = data.aws_subnets.public.ids[subnet_mapping.key]
      allocation_id = data.aws_eip.lb[subnet_mapping.key].id
    }
  }
}
```